# Traceback (most recent call last) EOFError

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input, eoferror

here is my code

```
t=input()
for q in range(t):
  s=raw_input()
  m,n=s.split(' ')
  ans = (m*n)*(m*n-1)
  if(m>1 and n>1):
    ans -= 4*(n-1)(m-2) + 4*(m-1)*(n-2)
  print ans
```

It has the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 1, in <module>
  t=raw_input()
 EOFError
```

What am i doing wrong ? please tell me 
here's the link

http://codepad.org/nmL96e68

Comment: codepad has no option for STDIN, try http://ideone.com/z328vR. On your system either enter those items manually after running file or use shell redirecting: `python file.py < input.txt`

Comment: ..and you cannot multiple two strings, so convert `m` and `n` to integers first.

Comment: Next time use a *real* python interpreter instead of a random online service.

Comment: @Ashwini thanks for your reply , now I'm getting this error can you please help me how to overcome by this error now. here's the link http://ideone.com/isvZP2

Comment: your code has multiple errors. first starts with `ans = (m*n)*(m*n-1)` because `m` and `n` are strings.

Comment: @Assians Don't mix tabs and spaces in Python code, always use 4 spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want to achieve, supposing `m` and `n` are integer type values,

```
t = input()
for q in range(t):
    s = raw_input()
    m, n = map(int, s.split(' '))
    ans = (m * n) * (m * n - 1)
    if m > 1 and n > 1:
        ans -= 4 * (n - 1) * (m - 2) + 4 * (m - 1) * (n - 2)
    print ans
```

Comment: thanks , yaa that's right , but why you use map , i don't want to use map , here is the modified link , can you please tell me how i overcome with this error now . http://ideone.com/isvZP2

Comment: i will suggest you to use `map`. After fixing your indentation, check line 9 in your code. change it from `ans -= 4*(n-1)(m-2) + 4*(m-1)*(n-2)` to `ans -= 4*(n-1)*(m-2) + 4*(m-1)*(n-2)`

Comment: it seems to me that my code and your code is same and has same indentation but still my code getting error , don't get that http://ideone.com/isvZP2

Comment: you have mixed up `tab` with `space`. in the first line of the `for` loop you have 4 space and the rest of the line has tab indentation. problem is in `s =raw_input()` line. make it's indentation `tab`.

Answer (score 1):

From the python doc on [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

So you can get an *EOFError* if your input is empty.

Avoid the use of input on line 1 and use raw_input instead. Try to add some error messages and validation to your code, like this:

```
import sys
try:
    t = int(raw_input())
except:
    print "No repetition parameters set, using 1"
    t = 1
for q in range(t):
    s = raw_input()
    try:
        m,n = s.split(' ')
        m = int(m)
        n = int(n)
    except:
        print "Invalid input, enter two integers separated by space"
        sys.exit(1)
    ans = (m*n)*(m*n-1)
    if(m > 1 and n > 1):
        ans -= 4*(n-1)*(m-2) + 4*(m-1)*(n-2)
    print ans
```

As someone suggested, always test your code on a real python interpreter.

Comment: The try/except is important here, because if the user press RETURN without writing any input, an EOFError is raised.

Comment: thanks for your reply buddy. sorry previous comment was deleted .